# Setting an empty column as a timestamp with time zone when creating a table in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, sqldatatypes

I am trying to create a table that has an column called `decay_date` that will have empty values (for the time being) but be formatted as a timestamp with time zone data type. If I simply do this:

```
CREATE TABLE my_schema.final_summed_table AS
  SELECT
   'Unstudied' AS table_name,
   r.region,
   r.state,
   r.co_fips,
   c.co_name AS county,
  'TIER 0' AS tiermetric_lfd,
  'UNASSESSED' AS val_combine_lfd,
  'Unmapped' AS mod_unmod_lfd,
  '' AS det_approx_lfd,
  '' AS decay_date_lfd TYPE TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NULL USING decay_date_lfd::TIMESTAMP
FROM my_schema.unmapped r, cnms.counties c
WHERE r.co_fips = c.co_fips
```

I get an error: `Syntax error near 'TYPE'` This table will be UNIONED later with another table that has the same `decay_date` column with the data type timestamp with time zone. How do I set the timestamp datatype for my `decay_date` column while creating my table?

Comment: `null::timestamptz AS decay_date_lfd`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`''` isn't a valid value for a timestamp to begin with. And you can't use `USING` like that in a column alias. That's only allowed (and needed) when you `ALTER` a table and change the type of a column.

Just select a `null` value and cast that to the desired type:

```
null::timestamptz AS decay_date_lfd
```

Comment: Both of these answers worked, but this was the one that was most easiest to apply.

Answer (score 1):

That is bad syntax. You'd have to cast the literal to the desired type.

So use a NULL value:

```
CREATE TABLE my_schema.final_summed_table AS
  SELECT
   CAST ('Unstudied' AS text) AS table_name,
   r.region,
   r.state,
   r.co_fips,
   c.co_name AS county,
   CAST ('TIER 0' AS text) AS tiermetric_lfd,
   CAST ('UNASSESSED' AS text) AS val_combine_lfd,
   CAST ('Unmapped' AS text) AS mod_unmod_lfd,
   CAST (NULL AS text) AS det_approx_lfd,
   CAST (decay_date_lfd AS timestamp with time zone) AS decay_date_lfd
FROM my_schema.unmapped r, cnms.counties c
WHERE r.co_fips = c.co_fips;
```

I'd avoid `CREATE TABLE ... AS` and use `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` instead.